# How to add Google-authenticated users to Firebase user system without password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a website that allows users to log in with either Firebase or Google authentication. Firebase authentication works fine, but I’m having trouble adding Google-authenticated users to the Firebase user system. Firebase requires an email and password to create a user, but Google authentication only provides the email.

What I'm currently doing is using the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` function and passing their Google email as the parameter, and generating a random password they can change in the future. However, I don't think this is the best approach to do it. I'm sure there is a better way to handle this situation, but I don't know how. Also, I have no idea how to log in the user using `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`, because I don't think it's safe to store the passwords directly and get them on login.

Is there a recommended way to handle this scenario? I appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm currently doing is using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) function and passing their Google email as the parameter, and generating a random password they can change in the future.

While this approach will definitely work, please note that there is another simpler one. So you can get the Google credentials as explained in the official documentation regarding [Firebase sign-in with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#web-namespaced-api_6) and call [Auth#signinwithcredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithcredential).